# How to write nunit test case(c#) for generic class which inherits another class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I am trying to write Nunit test cases for one generic class as shown below. But I am not getting how exactly I should write test case as writing like below does not even run could someone please help on this?

My main class is like :-

```
public class TestController<T> : ControllerBase
{
    private const string STATUS_OK_MESSAGE = "OK";
     
    [HttpGet]
    public ContentResult Get()
    {
       *** Some logic here *****
      return Content(STATUS_OK_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

My Test case that I tried is like below :-

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test1<T> where T : class
{
   TestController testController;
   
   [OneTimeSetUp]
   public void OneTimeSetup()
   {
      testController= new TestController();
   }

   [Test]
   public void Get()
   {
        var result = (ContentResult)testController.Get();
        Assert.AreEqual("OK", "OK");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not telling NUnit anywhere what to use for `T`. The `where` clause is for the compiler, not for NUnit. Therefore, NUnit has no way to construct your fixture, because it may only be constructed for a particular `T`.

More fundamentally, in your test code you make no use of `T`. If the controller class is generic then you would have to use TestController in the code. Or use a specific TestController type.

Basically, we need to know why you want your test to be generic. Or whether you really do. Do you have more than one TestController type in your application? Or is there just one? If just one, you don't need a generic test at all.

If you edit your question to explain a bit more of what you want to do, I'll add some suggested code here. But are several different things you may be trying to do and the code is different for each one.

UPDATE

Based on the info that you need multiple controllers, one way to write your test would be...

```
[TestFixture(typeof(TestController<Class1>)]
[TestFixture(typeof(TestController<Class2>)]
public class Test1<T> where T : ControllerBase, new()
{
   T testController;
   
   [OneTimeSetUp]
   public void OneTimeSetup()
   {
      testController = new T();
   }

   [Test]
   public void Get()
   {
        var result = (ContentResult)testController.Get();
        Assert.AreEqual("OK", "OK");
   }
}
```

This approach works only if your controllers all have a default constructor.

Comment: Hi @Charlie  thanks for reply. yes so I have more than one TestController type and will  definitely need generic type. If you could just give some sample test case for this it would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with Rhino Mocks

var PartialMock = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock(FileTypes.VEH);

and our VEHExport class extended with 
[image]

[image]
[image]

you can have similar look in your Nunit framework, it should be there.

Comment: Hi @Anish Sinha. Thanks for reply. okay sure will try to search something similar for Nunit